# How do you redirect and display programs output?

Tags: bash, shell, cmd, terminal

I have a program that contains prints or writelines or whatever. Is it possible for the program to both write to the console window and write to file?

`script.py > WriteToFile && Print to console`

Comment: `script.py | tee WriteToFile`

Comment: CMD is windows command shell.

Comment: Will `| tee` work on both windows command shell and a linux/osx terminal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239924/windows-batch-tee-command

Comment: Thanks for the link @dekkard

Comment: Why not have your script do that, instead of using redirection and/or `tee`?  (Which are fine solutions as well.)  Write to file, and write to output.  The dedicated output filename can be a (named) command line option.

Comment: Very simple, but could be helpful though: `script > output.txt & type output.txt`; of course the data are displayed only if the script has finished...